# which one is best way to store multiple values for a single field? Comma separated or Separate Table

Tags: mysql, database, csv, database-normalization

I want to store user followers and following member list. Now in order to this, i am thinking to create two columns namely FOLLOWING and FOLLOWER in USER table to store comma separated values of following and followers respectively.

```
USER TABLE FIELDS:

userid
firstname
lastname
date_of_birth
following   //in this we store multiple following_id as comma separated
follower    //in this we store multiple follower_id as comma separated
```

Another way is to create tables namely FOLLOWER and FOLLOWING to store user's followers and following members id in it.

```
USER TABLE FIELDS:

userid
firstname
lastname
date_of_birth
```

and

```
FOLLOWER TABLE FIELDS:

userid
follower_id (also is an user)
```

and

```
FOLLOWING TABLE FIELDS:

userid
following_id (also is an user)
```

Since i am learning database designing, i don't have enough knowledge. So, here i am not getting proper idea of which way is proper? I have searched that using comma separated way is not a good idea but at the same time is it a good way to have multiple tables with NF ? Is there any drawback of using JOINS? Or is there any other effective way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Tables look just fine. Just create right indexes and keys as necessary. CSV field in DB only make sense whey they're static(not mutating) values.

Comment: @DoSparKot one of his tables is unneccesary

Comment: @Alnitak From what I gather `If A follows B, not necessarily mean B follows A`. It's not a `friend` mapping.

Comment: @DoSparKot indeed, but if `A is following B` then `A is a follower of B`, i.e. his `following` and `follower` tables would be the same tables with the columns reversed.  In the single table model, if they were following each other you just need _two_ rows in the `following` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the above. One ***row per follower***. Normalize your data and using it will be easy. Make it an abstract mess like you're proposing and you're life will get tougher and tougher as your application grows.

Comment: from what I can see his second proposal is actually pretty close - it just has one too many tables in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you please elaborate your point i.e ONE ROW PER FOLLOWER in brief. How to store one row per follower?

Answer (score 5):

You need just *two* tables - one to list your `users`, and one to list who each user is `following`.

The resulting tables would be like your second proposal, except that the `followers` table is unnecessary because all of the required data is already in the `following` table - it's just keyed from the second column instead of the first.  That table will need an index on *both* columns.

The `following` table whould have one row per relationship *per direction*.  If the users are following each other, you would put *two* entries in the `following` table.

```
CREATE TABLE following (
    userid ... NOT NULL,
    following_id ... NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX idx_user ON following(userid);
CREATE INDEX idx_following on following(following_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_both ON following (userid, following_id); // prevents duplicates
```

To find the IDs that a particular user is following:

```
SELECT following_id FROM following WHERE userid = ?
```

or to find that user's followers:

```
SELECT userid FROM following WHERE following_id = ?
```

Use appropriate `JOIN` clauses if required to expand those queries to return the users' names.